# Can't get my recursive function to count letters in a string correctly (c++)

Tags: c++, recursion

I've got a homework assignment that requires me to use a recursive function to count the number of a's in a user given string. *I don't want the answer given to me, but if someone could give me a little guidance that would be great.* It correctly calls itself, but I can't figure out how to correctly count the number of a's. Here is my code.

```
int charCounter(string str, int counter)
{
    if (str == "")
    {
        return counter;
    }
    else if (str.substr(1) == "a");
    {
        counter++;
        return counter + charCounter(str.substr(1),counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: A `string` is made up of `char`s.

Comment: For a small string, use a debugger and step through the code line by line, entering the recursive calls. The *two* problems (at least) you have should become quite obvious quickly then.

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger or add cout statements to see what your functions does. Also double-check what the parameter to `substr()` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know that a string is an array of chars. E.g. "hey" => ['h','e', 'u'].

When you deal with recursive functions the first thing you need is your stop condition which you stated as str == "" or when str is empty.

For each time you call you recursive function you want to check if the string is empty then return the counter, otherwise you increment counter, remove one char from your string then you call recursively your function passing along the new str and the current counter.

Make sure when you call you recursive function set counter = 0

Pseudocode

```
recursiveStrCounter(str, counter) {
    if empty str {
       return counter
    }
    counter++
    remove one char from str
    return recursiveStrCounter(str, counter)
}

print recursiveStrCounter(str, 0)
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Very helpful information for a beginner, and learned a couple new things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

changing the function slightly will help

```
int countstring(string s) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return counter;
        else {
            if (s[0]== 'a')
                counter++;
            string newstring = s.substr(1);
            return counter + countstring(newstring);

        }
    }
```